# Issues installing composer correctly on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, laravel, terminal, installation, composer-php

I know there are some questions about how to install composer on SO, but they did not help me.

I am trying to install composer (for laravel). I have OS X El Capitan.

I downloaded composer like this:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /Users/blckbird/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.par
```

Next, I tried to execute the laravel installation:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Which did not work because:

```
-bash: composer: command not found
```

So I tried:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/composer
```

Which worked, however, I still can not execute composer (same error as above).

What am I doing wrong and how can I install composer correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your composer.phar is installed in /Users/blckbird/, try this for global installation:

```
sudo mv /Users/blckbird/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Note:** On some versions of OSX the /usr directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin. [More info](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).

Comment: I go the error `mv: rename /Users/blckbird/composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Not a directory`. So I executed `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` which also threw error `Not a directory`.

Comment: Try: sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin